# Migrating applications and services to Salesforce

Tags: webservices, service-cloud-console

I am a project manager at an education institute having 20,000 students (and growing)! We are currently heavily invested in compute and storage resources as we have purchased and maintained them in-house.

Looking at the future growth of our applications and scalability of demand (load-balancing), we have decided to transition all of our applications and services (authentications,data store, etc.) to the Cloud.

The following technologies are currently in use:

- Operating Systems (Order of importance)

  - Red Hat EL 6 and 7
  - CentOS 6 and 7
  - OpenSUSE 12 and 13
  - Windows Server 2008 R2 and 2012
- Programming Languages (Order of importance)

  - Java (Primary language for all public production systems)
  - Javascript
  - C# (Web Services)
  - Python 3 (Management and internal applications)
- Frameworks (Order of Importance)

  - Seam Framework (Primary framework for all public production systems)
  - Flask
  - Web.py (depreciated)
- Web and application Servers (No order)

  - Jboss
  - IIS
  - Apache

    - mod_wsgi
  - Nginx

    - uWSGI
- Authentication platforms

  - User Authentication
  - Directory Services (Apache or RHEL)
  - Microsoft Active Directory
- Database (Order of importance)

  - Oracle 12c and 11g (Production services)
  - Postgresql (Internal Applications)
- Plugin and Services

  - Social Media API (LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter)
  - Distribution Tools (Heroku, Docker, Ansible)
- Security

  - Certificates - SHA-2 (Komodo)
  - Network Isolation
  - Firewall
  - Virus scanning
  - Log monitoring and alerting
- Backup and disaster recovery

  - Multiple datacenters
  - Live replication
  - Load balancing
  - Backup and Recovery service

    - One image stored with service provider (backend)
    - One image stored on EMC Networker backup system
- Client support

  - Windows 7 and 10

    - Firefox
    - Chrome
    - IE
    - Edge
  - Mac OS X Yosemite+

    - Safari
    - Firefox
    - Chrome

Is there any documentation that I could refer to confirm whether our requirements will be matched? If you feel this question deserves another audience, then please let me know.

I will highly appreciate any help and/or alternative suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: can SFDC do it - yes, but it will be a project

Answer (score 0):

If you doing requirement analysis of your current implementation in SFDC that will be a entirely different thing. It is not simply changing the hosting from one host to another. It will be a quite big project from your current implementation but once it is implemented your life will be very easy to handle.

Salesforce is very powerful to handle enterprise application so here I am summarizing different aspects of your requirement in terms of Salesforce implementation.

**Operating System**

- It will be hosted in cloud so no operating system required.

**Programming Languages (Order of importance)**

- Apex will be development language so you need to implement everything from your current language to SFDC.

**User Authentication**

- Salesforce support Single sign-on which will allow active directory integration and other services including social services such as Facebook, Linkedin.

**Plugin and Services**

- Social Media API (LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter)  (I am not sure what is your requirement here but if you are looking for community you can use these API for login purpose)

**Distribution Tool**

- NA

**Security**

- Salesforce will manage your security part. You can read more about this on [trust page](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/learn)

**Backup and disaster recovery**

- Again, There is no need to worry about the backup and disaster. Salesforce manage that.You can again check Trust page for details about [disaster recovery](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/learn/datacenters) and backup

**Client support**

All Major browsers suppported. IE9, IE10, IE11, Chrome, Firefox, Safari